# Invalid syntax when trying to install NLTK on OS 10.10.5

Tags: python, macos, nlp, installation, nltk

Sorry about the basic nature of the question, but I'm new to programming/machine learning and simply can't figure this out. Also, related questions here haven't been able to solve this for me.  I'm attempting to install NLTK following the instructions found here: http://www.nltk.org/install.html.  I follow the instructions for Mac OS, but I just get an invalid syntax error for everything.

[view of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkYDd.png)

Not sure if there's something simple I'm missing.  I'm running Python 3.6(that I downloaded) on OS 10.10.5.  The Mac did come pre-installed with an earlier version of Python (2.7), not sure if this is an issue.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: `pip3 install --user --upgrade nltk` But do note that NLTK hasn't officially supported Python3.6. Code might break.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that you're trying to run pip from within the python shell, while what you want to do is simply run it from the Terminal app.

So just start a new terminal window (or exit the python shell in your existing terminal window using `exit()`) and you should be able to run the installation steps (for python3):

1. `pip3 install -U nltk`
2. *(optional)* `pip3 install -U numpy`
3. `python3` and then in the python shell `import nltk`

Comment: That worked, but I'm still unable to import nltk while using Python 3.6.  It imports for the 2.7 version.  Any idea why this is?  I successfully installed everything using pip3 instead of pip but it still won't import afterward.

Comment: I updated it (edit) for python3 with all of the installation steps. Do you get an error message for the import?

Comment: I was finally able to import it after changing pip to pip3 and using alvas' suggestion.